# PHP 5.5 to 5.6 strtotime() hangs

Tags: php

I have been testing the move from PHP 5.5 to 5.6 and cleaning up bugs.  I found one, I have no idea how to fix and my ISP is firm that the problem with my code.

It took 4 days to narrow the problem down to a strtotime() problem.  Take a look at the following.  I have been using a similar script for years, yet now when I test it under PHP 5.6, it fails.  The server just hangs and stops responding when I change the loop from 10 to 25.

```
<?
/*
test for PHP 5.6 and strtotime() not working correctly
for ($e2 = 0; $e2 < 25; $e2++) { // if this is set active, the script does not load and eventually times out under PHP 5.6
for ($e2 = 0; $e2 < 10; $e2++) { // if this is set active, the script completes properly under PHP 5.6
*/
    for ($e2 = 0; $e2 < 25; $e2++) {
        $today=date('Y-m-d',strtotime());
        $lastmodyear=date('Y-m-d',strtotime("+ $e2 months"));
        $lastmodY=date('Y',strtotime("+ $e2 years"));
        $contents .= "<div>Empty: $today / Month: $lastmodyear / Year: $lastmodY</div>";
    }
    echo "$contents";

?>
```

Comment: The function `strtotime()` to time expects a parameter, e.g. if you want the current time `strtotime('now')`. But that should already be an issue in older versions too.

Comment: I agree completely that it expects a parameter.  But is the correct response when not receiving a parameter to hang the session until it times out?  That is why I included it in the example.  In 5.5 without a parameter returns 1969-12-31 and then 5.6 without a parameter <10 returns 1970-01-01

Comment: I don't think the lack of parameter is the problem within the strtotime().  In my earlier testing, I considered that in my testing and ensured there was a parameter passed.  I have narrowed it down to something with looping the strtotime() function.  PHP 5.6 is quite mature so it would be hard to believe it's a bug within the strtotime() function.

Comment: How does your web site generally respond to errors?  Can you change the code to generate another syntax error and see if it hangs or reports a 500 error code.

Comment: Through my .htaccess, I simply pass the error code to another php file for handling 404 and 500 errors.  However in this case it times out with a generic 504 error. Not sure what you mean by generate another syntax error.

Comment: Bascially it also runs (with the notices) in php 5.6: [Fiddle in 5.6](https://3v4l.org/jKH5Y)    
So I may also guess something with the error handling may be different.

Comment: If you added another call to `strtotime()` without a parameter.  Although there is a limited amount of how much do you need to track this down or just solve the problem and move on?

Comment: With 5.5 I get the same results as the Fiddle example above.  However when I switch to 5.6, it hangs with no output what so ever.

Comment: Does it work when you fix the errors (adding parameter to `strotime` and initializing the `$contents` variable)?

Comment: Think I found the solution.  Don't agree, but I think it's all boiling down to the timezone.  Reading through the responses, I turned on the ini_set to display all errors (off by default).  Upon running the script I was able to get an error stating it's not safe to run date() without a set timezone.  So I added date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York"); to the beginning of the script and now PHP 5.6 completes with the same strtotime() missing parameter error I get eith 5.5.

Comment: Here is what is in my php.ini file for timezone.  Apparently it is not being recognized as a default.

[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://php.net/date.timezone
date.timezone = "America/New_York"

Comment: Not sure where the bug originates, but after the setting the timezone, both PHP 5.5 and 5.6 strtotime() without parameter now return 1969-12-31 as the default date.  Whereas 5.6 would return 1970-01-01.

Answer (score 0):

To pass on to others that may stumble across this problem.  Here is my solution.

Added this to the top of script:

```
date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");
```

Now it will complete properly under PHP 5.6:

```
<?
date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");
/*
test for PHP 5.6 and strtotime() not working correctly
for ($e2 = 0; $e2 < 25; $e2++) { // if this is set active, the script does not load and eventually times out under PHP 5.6
for ($e2 = 0; $e2 < 10; $e2++) { // if this is set active, the script completes properly under PHP 5.6
strtotime() expects at least 1 parameter // understood, but should not end with the session timing out with a 504 error and only when <25??
*/
    for ($e2 = 0; $e2 < 25; $e2++) {
        $today=date('Y-m-d',strtotime());
        $lastmodyear=date('Y-m-d',strtotime("+ $e2 months"));
        $lastmodY=date('Y',strtotime("+ $e2 years"));
        $contents .= "<div>Empty: $today / Month: $lastmodyear / Year: $lastmodY</div>";
    }
    echo "$contents";

?>
```